# I am new and struggling with java and I need assistance with code. Value keeps resetting to default

Tags: java, netbeans

## Help please

Please help with my program I am a bit new to coding and I do not know how to fix my problem. The code works without errors but with the wrong result. I am writing exam in a few days and would like some assistance.

```
package Practice1.pkg1;

import java.time.Year;
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class Sub1 {    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int age = 0;
        String name ="";
        String surname ="";
        int dob = 0;
        int year = Year.now().getValue(); 

        info( name, sur**strong text**name, age);
        calc(age, year, dob);
        result(name, surname, age, year, dob);
    }
    
    public static void info(String name, String surname, int age) {
        System.out.println("What is your name user?"); 
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your surname user?"); 
        Scanner input2= new Scanner(System.in);
        surname = input2.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is your age user?"); 
        Scanner input3= new Scanner(System.in);
        age = Integer.parseInt(input3.nextLine());
    }

    public static void calc(int age, int year, int dob) {
        dob = year - age;
    }

    public static void result(String name, String surname, int age, int year, int dob) {
        System.out.println("Welcome "+name+" "+ surname+" born in "+dob);
        //user in put returns back to default.
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the actual and the expected results ?

Comment: Java is pass by value, so you cannot reasign method parameters inside a method and see the changes outside of that method.

Comment: Remove the `dob` parameter from `calc`, have `calc` method `return (year - age);` , then call `int dob = calc(age, year);` .